# Sending data from WinForms to Website database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, web, send

I'm creating win forms application which has a database with some data. In application I'm generating new information which also goes to database. 
I have an idea to put that data into website.

My question:  Is it possible to send new generated data to the website database by click one button from winforms application ? Can't find any info about it. Any suggestions ?

Regards.

Comment: Often the website would use the same database as the win forms app. But even if they are separate then yes, you can do that and there are many options. The question needs more focus.

Comment: Yes, search for REST API. In NET there are many options to connect a client (winform) to a server using the standard library or custom ones. Intro https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Comment: Whether you use a website or WinForms application you can access the same database.   In fact you can access as many databases as you wish. Remember applications tend to be split so that your data access code is not embedded within your user interface code e.g. Win Form or Web page

Comment: The easiest solution is using a database.

    Create remote database which both web application and windows application can communicate
    Use timer object to frequently query the database and display new messages are required

Complex solution involves creating UDP/TCP connections between applications.

Sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C